# Range.Calculate not updating the values in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that makes a lot of calculation, including arrays, that is working great, with the exception of one line that it is not updating when calculated.

To calculate that range, which is a sum of the above lines, I am using:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Range(Worksheets("Report2").Cells(40,4).Address & ":" & Worksheets("Report2").Cells(41, 33).Address).Dirty
Application.Range(Worksheets("Report2").Cells(40,4).Address & ":" & Worksheets("Report2").Cells(41,33).Address).Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

It would be great if anyone could provide any light into this.
Thank you.

Rgds,
Rodnei

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are in Automatic calculation mode and Report2 is not the active worksheet:

Range.Dirty is buggy and always works on the active sheet

Range.Calculate will not recalculate undirtied cells in Automatic mode.

See http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsg.htm for other limitations of Range.Calculate

and http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm for more information on using VBA to calculate formulas.

Comment: Thank you Charles. I was aware of the nuances of calculation methods, but was intrigued by what was going on with my code. I think I did a silly mistake on the sum formula that is in the cell I was trying to update. the @sum() formula was picking up itself in the range. Let me see if this is what is avoiding the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - You had a slight oversight....

On the first line you've put in `"Report2"` and on the next line you've put in `"Report1"` for the sheet name.

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: Thanks John, but I misspelled it. I cannot get to work even with that fix.

Comment: That is weird - I've done this many times before and it worked for me... Can you post some more code? Also, as an FYI, you also need to change the `Report1` on the second range on the second line of your question...

Answer (score 0):

To piggy-back on @John Bustos suggestion, you also have an unnecessary space between the ", 30"

Corrected code with the "Report1" and ", 30" errors fixed would show:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Range(Worksheets("Report2").Cells(40,4).Address & ":" & Worksheets("Report2").Cells(41,33).Address).Dirty
Application.Range(Worksheets("Report2").Cells(40,4).Address & ":" & Worksheets("Report2").Cells(41,33).Address).Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

If you are having problems with the second line, try activating the sheet before you call the cells dirty with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report2").Activate
```

Comment: I also just noticed that the Application.ScreenUpdating is switched to  False at the end of the code. This should be reversed because after the code runs, you won't see values changing until the screen is allowed to update again.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I fixed the space.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is another problem with your code if Report2 is not the active worksheet: the range calculate will be calculating the equivalent range on the active sheet

I think what you actually mean to do is something more like this

```
Worksheets("Report2").Cells(40, 4).Resize(2, 30).calculate
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, I had in previous lines of my code set the report 2 as the active one.